# Same for_loop code, print different results the second time run

Tags: python, for-loop

Here is my code :

```
for i in range (x):
    print(i)
    x=5
```

I use Spyder 3.3.2 on a Windows 10 platform. When I tried the for loop with the code I've  written above I found an interesting problem. 
The first time I clicked the green Run file(F5) button it printed:

```
0
1
2
3
```

But the second time I run the file it printed:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Could someone please explain what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to invite you to think a second about your code real hard. At what point do you define `x` for the `range(x)`

Comment: you obviously have defined `x=4` somewhere before the loop, then you ran the loop where x is defined as `x=5` and your output changes

Comment: Thank you Vulpex. I remove all variables and tried again. It just gave an error: NameError: name 'x' is not defined. I think this may be caused by a previously used variable X.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the loop variable x outside

```
x=5
for i in range (x):
    print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
```